# Edittext field enable and disable using button in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I am working on an Android application in which I want to make my edittext enable and disable by using a "EDIT" button. I am making something like if I press the button it will enable edittexts and if I again press EDIT button then it will disable EditTexts.

My code snippet is given below. In following condition on first attempt it works fine, but after clicking again it just return "click1".

```
editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clickCount == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    fName.setEnabled(true); 
                    lName.setEnabled(true); 
                    mailText.setEnabled(true);  
                    mobileText.setEnabled(true);    
                }
                clickCount = 1;


  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        fName.setEnabled(false);
        lName.setEnabled(false);
        mailText.setEnabled(false);
        mobileText.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
  editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
              if (clickCount == 0){
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  fName.setEnabled(true); 
                  lName.setEnabled(true); 
                  mailText.setEnabled(true);  
                  mobileText.setEnabled(true);    
                  clickCount = 1;
            }else if(clickCount == 1){
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  fName.setEnabled(false);
                  lName.setEnabled(false);
                  mailText.setEnabled(false);
                  mobileText.setEnabled(false);
                  clickCount = 0;
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `if-else` and `isEnabled` :

```
if(fName.isEnabled())
   fName.setEnabled(false);
else
   fName.setEnabled(true);
//do the same for other Views
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But i want to make it in single method. By doing this line of codes should be increased because i have almost 10-15 edittexts.

Comment: @muhammadusmankhan You welcome :) What do you mean by **single method**? You can do this code in the `onClick` method.

Answer (score 1):

u can try this too

```
boolean clickCount =false;

editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       if (!clickCount){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           fName.setEnabled(true); 
           lName.setEnabled(true); 
           mailText.setEnabled(true);  
           mobileText.setEnabled(true);    
           clickCount = true;
         }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            fName.setEnabled(false);
            lName.setEnabled(false);
            mailText.setEnabled(false);
            mobileText.setEnabled(false);
            clickCount = false;//this line is optional
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 function :

```
public static void disableEditText(EditText editText) {
        editText.setFocusable(false);
        editText.setEnabled(false);
        editText.setCursorVisible(false);

     }
```

And

```
public static void enableEditText(EditText editText) {
    editText.setFocusable(true);
    editText.setEnabled(true);
    editText.setCursorVisible(true);
 }
```

It work for me, I hope it will help you!

Thanks!